# SQL Server AVG function to return NULL if all values are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, average

I have a table similar to this

```
+--+-----+----+
|ID|Entry|Exit|
+--+-----+----+
|18|32154|NULL|
+--+-----+----+
|19|NULL |NULL|
+--+-----+----+
```

When I select AVG(Entry) it correctly gives me 32154, when I select AVG(Exit) it blows up saying "Operand data type void type is invalid for avg operator."

How can I get NULL as the average for a column that only has NULL values?

Thanks,

Comment: What data type is Exit? As the error message clearly says, its data type is not compatible with AVG.

Comment: The datatype is float and the error message says that void (NULL) is incompatible. The problem here is that AVG(NULL) returns an error instead of NULL.

Comment: Then something is strange because "void type" in the error suggests that this is not a real table but a derived table. See here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/27/sql-server-puzzle-involving-null-resolve-error-operand-data-type-void-type-is-invalid-for-sum-operator/

Comment: AS @Pondlife said, is this really a physical table?, or is the result of another query?

Comment: It is the resultset of a subquery, but how does that change the behaviour of the AVG function?

Comment: It changes the behaviour because your subquery is probably doing something like this: `SELECT NULL AS Exit`, **without** specifying a datatype for that column, that's the real problem. It should be like this: `SELECT CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Exit` instead

Comment: I think you need to cast to float as all the values are null and type cannot be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Exit column doesn't have a data type that is compatible with the SUM function.

You can run this query to see that you indeed get NULL from SUM if all values are NULL (and a proper data type)

```
select sum(a) from (select convert(int, null) a union select null) a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using CASE like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Exit) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE AVG(Exit) END AS MyAverage 
FROM MyTable
```

I think The problem is with the column name. Just change the column name to ExitCol and check.

In that case even `SELECT AVG(ExitCol) AS MyAverage FROM MyTable` also will work

Comment: unfortunately the SUM function behaves the same way and SUM(NULL) gives the same error.

Comment: I checked with float datatype also and the above query just working fine. I think The problem is with the column name. Just change the column name to ExitCol and check.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select avg(isnull(Exit,0)) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

use `set xact_abort off` to get it to return null

```
  declare @a table (id int, amount numeric(10,2))
  insert into @a values (1, null), (2,null), (3,null) 

  set xact_abort off

  select AVG(amount)
  from @a
```